Why is my QPainterPath border not visible on the right and bottom of my window?
I am trying to build a custom shaped translucent QWidget using a QPainterPath which draws the shape using QBrush. When I draw the shape as a border (1.0 px), only the left and top edge shows up.


I am not sure if this is related to my calculations in the code or an inherent limitation of how the window is getting drawn?
import functools as _functools
import typing as _t

from Qt import (
    QtCore as _QtCore,
    QtGui as _QtGui,
    QtWidgets as _QtWidgets,
)


class MyWindow(_QtWidgets.QWidget):
    _MAX_WIDTH = 600
    _CLOSE_BUTTON_SIZE: _t.ClassVar[_t.Tuple[int, int]] = (15, 15)
    _CLOSE_BUTTON_TOOLTIP: _t.ClassVar[str] = "Close"
    _BORDER_WIDTH = 1.0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self._tip_palette = _QtWidgets.QToolTip.palette()
        self._setup_ui()
        self._setup_connections()
        # TODO: Remove after testing.
        self._setup_pdb()

        self.setAttribute(_QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setWindowFlag(_QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.allow_close(True)
        self._window_shape_path = self._get_window_shape_path()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self._window_shape_path = self._get_window_shape_path()
        return super().resizeEvent(event)

    def set_message(self, text: str) -> None:
        self._message_label.setText(text)

    def allow_close(self, allow: bool):
        self._close_t_button.setHidden(not allow)

    def _get_window_shape_path(self) -> _QtGui.QPainterPath:
        print(self.size())
        shape_size = _QtCore.QSizeF(self.size())
        print(shape_size)

        origin = _QtCore.QPointF(0.0, 0.0)
        bottom_left = _QtCore.QPointF(origin.x(), shape_size.height())
        bottom_right = _QtCore.QPointF(
            shape_size.width(), bottom_left.y()
        )
        top_right = _QtCore.QPointF(bottom_right.x(), origin.y())

        shape_path = _QtGui.QPainterPath(origin)
        shape_path.lineTo(bottom_left)
        shape_path.lineTo(bottom_right)
        shape_path.lineTo(top_right)
        shape_path.lineTo(origin)

        return shape_path

    def paintEvent(self, event: _QtGui.QPaintEvent) -> None:
        painter = _QtGui.QPainter(self)
        brush = self._tip_palette.background()

        pen = _QtGui.QPen()
        pen.setColor(_QtCore.Qt.red)
        pen.setWidthF(self._BORDER_WIDTH)

        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawPath(self._window_shape_path)

    def _setup_ui(self):
        self._message_label = _QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self._message_label.setWordWrap(True)
        self._message_label.setForegroundRole(self._tip_palette.ToolTipText)
        self._button = _QtWidgets.QPushButton()

        self._close_t_button = _QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self._close_t_button.setIcon(
            _QtWidgets.QApplication.style().standardIcon(
                _QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_TitleBarCloseButton
            )
        )
        self._close_t_button.setToolTip(self._CLOSE_BUTTON_TOOLTIP)
        self._close_t_button.setFixedSize(*self._CLOSE_BUTTON_SIZE)

        self._main_layout = _QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self._main_layout.addWidget(
            self._close_t_button, alignment=_QtCore.Qt.AlignRight
        )
        self._main_layout.addWidget(self._message_label)
        self._main_layout.addWidget(self._button)
        self.setLayout(self._main_layout)
        self.setMaximumWidth(self._MAX_WIDTH)
        self._message_label.setMaximumWidth(
            self.maximumWidth() - self._main_layout.contentsMargins().right()*2
        )

    def _setup_connections(self):
        self._button.clicked.connect(_functools.partial(self.close))

    def _setup_pdb(self):
        self._pdb_shortcut = _QtWidgets.QShortcut(_QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+p"), self)
        self._pdb_shortcut.activated.connect(self._launch_pdb)

    def _launch_pdb(self):
        import pdb

        pdb.set_trace()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys as _sys

    app = _QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = MyWindow()
    widget.set_message("This is quite a long message that I do not care about!")
    widget.allow_close(False)
    widget.resize(400, 400)
    widget.show()
    _sys.exit(app.exec_())


See the Coordinate System docs: when drawing in the default aliased mode, coordinates correspond to the bottom right pixel at the given points, so if you want to draw "within" a rectangle, you must subtract 1 from the right and bottom. Note that if you just need the widget edges, doing all those point definitions is pointless (pun intended): create the path without origin and do path.addRect(QRectF(self.rect().adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1))), or just avoid that function at all, and simply do painter.drawRect(self.rect().adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1)).
